# Unit can't be called in this context by implicit receiver

Tags: kotlin

I am following this Kotlin example (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/kotlin-dsl.html#Editing+Kotlin+DSL) and trying to write a kotlin script for my CI.

This is my code snippet

```
steps {
    script {
        name = "Style check"
        id("StyleCheck")
        enabled = false
        scriptContent = """
            #!/bin/bash

            make docker run="make ci lint"
        """.trimIndent()
    }
```

I get an Error for the id() call which says

[image: Error message]

- What does the error message mean?
- How can I use `id()` call as given in the example?

Comment: My guess is that the `id` function is not imported, which is the real error.

Comment: My IDE, IntelliJ is supposed to auto import. and I also do * import as per the example.

Answer (score 6):

This error happens because the method `id(String)` is defined in an outer scope, and to prevent you from accidentally using the wrong method, Kotlin gives you a compiler error.

In your case you should make sure that there's no other `id` that you want to use. [Perhaps you wanted to use the property named `id` instead of the method?](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/unit-cant-be-called-in-this-context-by-implicit-receiver/22133)

---

**Note that neither of the options below might not have the same effect as you want. There might be a reason why the API is written like this to not allow you to call methods from outer receivers from inside inner scopes.**

In order to use an explicit receiver, you can use `this@methodName` to call it. In this case, `this@steps`.

```
steps {
    script {
        name = "Style check"
        this@steps.id("StyleCheck")
        enabled = false
        scriptContent = """
            #!/bin/bash

            make docker run="make ci lint"
        """.trimIndent()
    }
}
```

To understand exactly what's going on, and another way of using an explicit receiver, you could also do something like the below, where you save the `this` scope in a variable and then call it inside the `script` scope.

```
steps {
    val stepsThis = this
    script {
        name = "Style check"
        stepsThis.id("StyleCheck")
        enabled = false
        scriptContent = """
            #!/bin/bash

            make docker run="make ci lint"
        """.trimIndent()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also use the qualified this (`this@SomeClass`) https://kotlinlang.org/docs/this-expressions.html in this scenario?

Comment: @DavidRawson Yes indeed. Although not with a class, but with the name of the outer method. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error when working with jetpack compose when I was writing the code below.

In my case the context was not clear.

It was giving this error.

`'fun item(key: Any? = ..., content: LazyItemScope.() -> Unit): Unit' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary`

It says Unit can't be called in this context. Therefore I changed the context and everything got right.

Error code:

```
LazyColumn {
       items(items = items) { word ->
           if (word != null) {
               WordColumnItem(word = word) {
                   onSelected(word)
               }
           }
           // Notice the context: within `items()` call
           if (items.itemCount == 0) {
               item(
                   content = { EmptyContent("No words") }
               )
           }
       }
   }
```

Correct code:

```
LazyColumn {
        items(items = items) { word ->
            if (word != null) {
                WordColumnItem(word = word) {
                    onSelected(word)
                }
            }
        }
        // Context changed: outside `items()` call
        if (items.itemCount == 0) {
            item(
                content = { EmptyContent("No words") }
            )
        }
    }
```

Although I don't know how to use the explicit receiver (if necessary).

Solution

1. I think error is clear.
2. You can use explicit receiver.

Comment: You don't explain what "explicit receiver" is. So **how** can it be used?